# Compress-Archive given in a script includes the script itself

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

How do I get `Compress-Archive` to only compress subfolder structure? As it is now the script itself is included in the .zip. Or is it possible to filter that out?

The code I got is as follows:

```
if (!($PSScriptRoot)) { Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path -Parent }
$destination  = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path -Parent
$source = (Get-ChildItem $PSScriptRoot)
$date = Get-Date -UFormat "%Y-%m-%d"
$zipfile = $destination + "\createdOn" + $date + ".zip"

#Check if file exists
if ([System.IO.File]::Exists($zipfile))
{
    Clear-Host
    Write-Host "File created: " $zipfile
    Compress-Archive -DestinationPath $zipfile -Force -Path $source -CompressionLevel Optimal
}
else
{
    Clear-Host
    Write-Host "File created: " $zipfile
    Compress-Archive -DestinationPath $zipfile -Force -Path $source -CompressionLevel Optimal
}
```

Comment: How do you expect to be able to use `Compress-Archive` in PowerShell v2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$source = (Get-ChildItem $PSScriptRoot -exclude $MyInvocation.MyCommand)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you set `$source` to the child items of `$PSScriptRoot` (the parent folder of the script), and then create an archive from those items, why would the resulting archive ***not*** contain the script that is one of the child items of that very folder?

Remove the script file from `$source` to avoid its inclusion in the archive:

```
$source = Get-ChildItem $PSScriptRoot |
          Where-Object { $_.FullName -ne $PSCommandPath }
```